# How do I get the ID using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to get the value of the id after clicking the button, so that i can use it to reference a particular table.

```html
<input type="button" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"  onclick="delBtn(<?php echo $id; ?>)"> 
<script>    
    function delBtn(btnX){

        var itemId = btnX;
        alert(itemId);
        var x; 
        var y =confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item ?');

        if(y == true){
            x = 'You pressed Ok';
            console.log(x);
            `$`("button[id='"+itemId+"']").closest("tr").effect("highlight", {
            color:'#4BADF5'}, 400);
            $("button[id='"+itemId+"']").closest("tr").fadeout();`
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `onclick="delBtn('<?php echo $id; ?>')"` ???  But describe your issue. Error in console? And why do you need to pass ID here, i still don't get it?

Comment: FYI, IDs ***must*** be unique on document context, sounds like you are using duplicates IDs, more than one button with same ID. Anyway, all this question not really makes much sense

Comment: @A.Wolff I have a table of items from a database, i want to delete a row dynamically using jquery but i have to uniquely identify each row, so i added a click function to the button to capture the row id then I will use the row ID to delete the row.

Answer (score 1):

> Why you are not using "attr" to get id

```
$('button').click(function(){
 alert(this.id);  // you can also use $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for ALL buttons on the page. It will get the button that is clicked, and will return the ID attribute value of the button. So you can have 5 buttons with all different ID's, and when one of them is clicked it will return the ID of the clicked button.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u1hcjtz1/)**

Comment: Could you please edit your question and explain the solution?

Comment: @Magnilex better now?

Answer (score 0):

If the button is added dynamically use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#your_id', function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   return id;
});
```

Comment: Where the return value goes to?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(id);
});
});
```

Comment: You cannot return value from click handler

Answer (score 0):

Use id:

```
function delBtn(btnX){ //btnX is not id, it's parameter only
var itemId = btnX.id; //so you need to use id
alert(itemId);
.....
```

But put this onclick in html:

```
onclick="delBtn(this)"
```

Comment: putting .... in a code example generally means 'more code here/add code here' etc rather then forgetting to close the function

Comment: @Bhoejendra Sah Thanks for you comment, but how will I reference the id using jquery to do something like this $("What will i use here to reference the ID ").closest("tr").effect("highlight", {
            color:'#4BADF5'}, 400);

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
<input type="button" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="yourclass">

  $(".yourclass").click(function(){
    var id=$(".yourclass").attr("id");
    alert(id);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could store the ID making it easier to access in the scope.

```
<input type="button" class="js-item-id" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="Remove">

<script>
    var itemId; 

    function delBtn() {

        var x; 
        var y = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item ?');

        // If y is true...
        if(y) {

            x = 'You pressed Ok';
            console.log(x);
            $("button[id='"+itemId+"']").closest("tr").effect("highlight", {
            color:'#4BADF5'}, 400);
            $("button[id='"+itemId+"']").closest("tr").fadeout();

            // Show me the ID!
            alert('You deleted item ID  #' + itemId + '.');
        }
    }

    $('.js-item-id').on('click', function() {

        // Return and store 'this' ID. e.g, if the buttons id was '1234',
        // it would return '1234'.
        itemId = $(this).attr('id');

        // Now, call the @delBtn() function.
        delBtn();
    });
</script>
```

Plus, I don't know if you meant to do this when copying your code, but you had a typo:

```
$("button[id='"+itemId+"']").closest("tr").fadeout();`
```

You have a trailing comma. It should be:

```
$("button[id='"+itemId+"']").closest("tr").fadeout();
```